# 'About this Mac' will not work anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, system-information

A'About this Mac' will not open anymore. How can I fix it. I have only had this computer a month and it was working before.

Comment: What happens when you select the menu item **(Apple) > About this Mac** ?

Answer (score 2):

is there anything specific you can tell us about this problem?
For example, when you click 'about this mac' does the tab flash, confirming that you have in fact clicked it? and if so are you merely receiving a "rainbow spinning wheel of death" issue?

Either way, I have done some research into this and it appears that you are not alone in this problem. Most people have suggested simply bypassing the problem by launching the "`System Information`" application found under the "`Utilities`" folder inside "`Applications"`, which will give you a far more in-depth insight into your mac than the "about this mac" tab ever will. However this is an unusual problem which should not be placated simply by bypassing it.

To solve this problem  i would suggest a few things, firstly: what was the last thing that you did before this error appeared, it could involve installing something odd or an unusual system crash (which may not have been your fault). If it was something unusual than it may be related to the error and could solve it through its reversal (if at all possible).

The second is to try and repair your disk permissions, by entering the `Disk Utility` application (`Applications/Utilities` folder again), and clicking `verify` and finally `repair`, which may well solve the problem. After this, i suggest a complete restart of the computer.
**

- Suggestion source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2686259

**

If worse comes to worst, you can always completely reset the machine, however this is somewhat overkill for such a minor issue.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: When I click on it nothing happens. I have tried opening the System Information in Utilities and it will not open and says. You can’t open the application “System Information” because it may be damaged or incomplete.

Comment: Yeah thats an odd one, this system error would likely be best fixed either by a complete system reset or by you verifying and then repairing disk permissions in Disk utility.

Comment: Is there another way to get into repairing disk permissions?

Comment: Disk utility is by far the easiest method, with plenty of 'how-to's on the internet. However one possible alternative is too open up the terminal and enter: "sudo diskutil repairPermissions /" without the quotation marks. This will produce exactly the same result as the Disk Utility option by repairing your primary hard drive.

Comment: Terminal will not open it says it is damaged or incomplete. Of all the files in Utilities only 5 will open the rest all say they are damaged or incomplete.

Comment: This sounds like a serious case of disk corruption. As disk utility cannot be opened to rectify this, i would suggest firstly shutting down the computer and restarting in Verbose mode (hold 'command v' on startup (immediately after chime noise)). Take a picture of this for future reference and tell me if this hangs anywhere and does not proceed to standard launch (which it is meant too).

Comment: Secondly, using a similar method, relaunch the computer and hold 'command R' to relaunch in recovery mode (remember to hold the keys immediately after chime noise). This will allow you too (with an internet connection) reinstall the operating system. It is also worth mentioning that you are about to loose all your data, sorry :/ For more information i would suggest: [This Page](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-reinstall-mac-os-x-using-internet-recovery-3593641/)